# Can't import kivy in Pycharm due to this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, kivy

Many people seem to have this problem but I haven't seen a way yet that allowed me to solve it. I reinstalled kivy and that didn't solve my problem. I saw that I should type in "pip -V" in the command line as well as "python -V". However, that didn't help: My pip version is 20.1 (Python 3.7) and my Python version is 3.7.6, so they both are for Python 3.7.

Does anyone know the solution to this? This is all on Windows 10 by the way

Oh and: I tried these 6 steps too:
Click on Files on top left corner.
Click on settings.
Click on Project and click on project interpreter.
Click on (➕) icon on right.
Click on "Search" and type "Kivy" you will find a lot of packages, then choose Kivy and install it.

and that didn't work either

Comment: When you click on `Settings->Python Interpreter`, you may see a dropdown list of Python version choices for `Python Interpreter`. If you see more than one choice,  make sure that there is a Kivy package listed for each one.

Comment: Other than pip, "setuptools" also is listed (Version 46.1.3). Does that mean I also need to "make sure that there is a Kivy package listed" for setuptools? And how do I do that?

Comment: The `pip` and `setuptools` packages are the minimums. The `File->Settings->Project` allows you to select which `Python` interpreter to use for that project. If that project uses `Kivy`, then `Kivy` must appear in the list of packages for that `Python` interpreter. If it does not appear, then you must install `Kivy` for that interpreter.

Comment: Okay so I tried installing Kivy in Pycharm (I already had installed it in the command line) and I got this:ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1. It then goes on to say this: "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\danny\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe'." Would you possibly know what to do about that? The executed command was "pip install kivy", which I already tried

Comment: In a terminal, try running `C:\Users\danny\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install kivy`.